How to update style for DataGrid component?
I'm trying to update the style of Columns display option in Material UI but I couldn't find way to do it
I want to change the input border color and change the color of checkbox
I tried to do it like this
sx={{
  '& .MuiDataGrid-paper': {
            color: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
            '& .MuiDataGrid-panelWrapper': {
              background: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
            },
              '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.dark} !important`,
              },
              '& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
                color: `${theme.palette.secondary.dark} !important`,
              },
            },
}}



If the dialog uses portal, it is not rendered inside the datagrid. It is not children of a datagrid, you can't access it like this & .MuiDataGrid-paper
Depending of the version of the mui you are using, there are props in datagrid that allow you to pass props to its inner components.
In version 7:
   slotProps={{
       columnMenu: {
         sx: {
          ...styles here
         }
      }
   }}

In version 5:
componentsProps={{
     columnMenu: {
        sx: {
           ...style here
        }
     }
}}

Your style has to be adapted to the real DOM. You won't need & .MuiDataGrid-paper selector.

none of these works ,it don't have sx props in it only style

Do you use typescript? It complains about it when you pass sx, but it should work. Try doing this: columnMenu: {sx: {backgroundColor: '#ff0000 !important'}} with slotProps or componentProps.  If the background is applied, then you can style it however you want

You can do it using sx props or overriding default styles with emotions. I would say the best approach is doing it with sx props. But i think in your code you have missed some targeted valid classes. i'll have the corrected one below according to my knowledge.
 sx={{
  '& .MuiDataGrid-paper': {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
    '& .MuiDataGrid-panelWrapper': {
      background: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
    },
  },
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.dark} !important`, // Input border color
    },
    '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.light} !important`, // Hover effect
    },
    '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.main} !important`, // Focused state
    },
  },
  '& .MuiCheckbox-root': {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main, // Checkbox color
    '&.Mui-checked': {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.dark, // Checked state
    },
  },
}}


 


I tried this also and not working, did it works for you ?
